# Cannot install kenlm package in anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, kenlm

When trying to install the [python wrapper of kenlm](https://github.com/kpu/kenlm) from pip within an anaconda environment, I get the error:

```
(lm_1b) adamg:lm_1b adamg$ pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
Collecting https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
     - 4.4MB 51.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: kenlm
  Running setup.py install for kenlm ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/2l/hd8b8vx566ld71lfd8hjglbc0000gn/T/pip-9yzty3hd-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2l/hd8b8vx566ld71lfd8hjglbc0000gn/T/pip-aff_d2b8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'kenlm' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/util
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/lm
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/util/double-conversion
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/python
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/include -arch x86_64 -I. -I/Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/include/python3.6m -c util/pool.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/util/pool.o -O3 -DNDEBUG -DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6 -std=c++11
    In file included from util/pool.cc:1:
    In file included from ./util/pool.hh:4:
    /Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/bin/../include/c++/v1/cassert:21:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
    #include <assert.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/adamg/anaconda2/envs/lm_1b/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/2l/hd8b8vx566ld71lfd8hjglbc0000gn/T/pip-9yzty3hd-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2l/hd8b8vx566ld71lfd8hjglbc0000gn/T/pip-aff_d2b8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2l/hd8b8vx566ld71lfd8hjglbc0000gn/T/pip-9yzty3hd-build/
```

The `pip` command works outside a conda environment, but then kenlm is not active within the environment. I was also able to run this from an AWS ec2 instance running linux, so maybe it's a Mac OSX issue. Any idea how can this be solved?

Comment: Try running the pip install from inside Anaconda prompt

Comment: That's what I've tried, and what leads to this error

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, it works fine outside of a conda environment.

Comment: Are you sure kenlm works with python2?

Comment: Installing from Anaconda Prompt worked for me on anaconda3 and windows

Comment: Perhaps the error relates to availability of c compoler on a system?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, and how I can check and correct it?

Comment: `conda create -n condapy27 python=2.7 anaconda`, this will install more library for the conda env, it works for both python2 and 3

Comment: @Gang Doesn't that just create a new environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac usually there is a problem on clang with different libraries that are missing. In most of this cases install Xcode will solve the problem. Also, in case this does not, you can also run in terminal `xcode-select --install`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks